# Как установить библиотеку для pillow?

Tags: python, pil, pillow, django

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как установить библиотеку `libfreetype` для `pillow`. У меня `windows7+python3.3`.

Я скачал библиотеку `libfreetype`, но дальше не знаю что делать...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте установить pillow с [этой](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) страницы, вполне возможно там уже всё включено.

Comment: я как раз с этой устанавливал

Comment: есть ещё такой проект http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/ посмотрите может там есть ваша библиотека и её можно использовать.